# How i change the dataTables_filter css class

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

i'm develop a web page in asp and i use the DataTable plugin. I want change the style in the dataTables_filter class, but i don't find this .css class and i don't know how do it.

`<div class="dataTables_filter" id="tabla_reserva_filter" style=""></div>`

I would like to find .css and to modify the style.

Thanks,

Best regards.

O. Melián.

Comment: wats the dataTable version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the css file for jQuery DataTables on GitHub (as of May 27th, 2013),
you will note that lines 61-67 have the `css class name` in question.

https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css#L61-67

```
/*
 * Filter
 */
.dataTables_filter {
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

But rather than attempting to change the source `.css` file, you might also consider writing your own css rule that overrides whatever properties you see fit in a stylesheet that comes *after* the datatables default css.

Comment: Thanks!!, you're right, it is better to create my css rule. Worls well! :).

Thanks!

Best regards! :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using one of the custom stlyes make sure you load the javascript files in the correct order:

```
 "~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
 "~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"
```